# Invalid signed assertion in response

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am attempting to create a custom identity provider (based on https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestIdPCore) but using HTTT-POST binding. The issue I am having is that when the service provider tries to validate the authn response they are getting errors ("actual digest value does not match expected"). I have also attempted to use a third party tool validating the xml response and was getting an error like "The XML has been altered after signing."

I am signing the assertion on the response using a certificate in the key store on the server where the service is running.

Answer (score 0):

The XML need to keep the same plain format for the signatur validation to succeed.

You probably need to debug to find the problem.

- Do you IdP work with a sample RP, e.g. https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCore
- Do you have different RP's and do someone work?

Comment: I have tried a sample RP and was getting the same issue and I currently only have one RP that is an actual external party. I think part of the issue was some of my code dealing with setting up the request/response was out of order. When I did not explicitly try to sign only the assertion (sign response) I was able to get it to work and validate.

Comment: I was trying to do something like 

`saml2AuthnResponse.Config.AuthnResponseSignType = inResponseTo?.Config?.AuthnResponseSignType ?? _config.AuthnResponseSignType;
saml2AuthnResponse.Config.SignatureAlgorithm = inResponseTo?.Config?.SignatureAlgorithm ?? _config.SignatureAlgorithm;
saml2AuthnResponse.SignatureAlgorithm = inResponseTo?.SignatureAlgorithm ?? _config.SignatureAlgorithm;`